# Error en doble bucle for

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for, bucles

Tengo un problema en este bucle:

```
IMFs = ['x', 'x - imf1', 'x - imf1 - imf2', 'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3', 'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4', 'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5', 'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5 - imf6',
    'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5 - imf6 - imf7', 'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5 - imf6 - imf7 - imf8', 'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5 - imf6 - imf7 - imf8 - imf9',
    'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5 - imf6 - imf7 - imf8 - imf9 - imf10', 'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5 - imf6 - imf7 - imf8 - imf9 - imf10 - imf11', 
    'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5 - imf6 - imf7 - imf8 - imf9 - imf10 - imf11 - imf12']
IMF_names = ['imf1', 'imf2', 'imf3', 'imf4', 'imf5', 'imf6', 'imf7', 'imf8', 'imf9', 'imf10', 'imf11', 'imf12']

for name in IMF_names:
    imf = eval(name)
    for IMF in IMFs:
        imf = my_get_next_imf(eval(IMF), zoom=(100,600))
```

Quiero iterar la lista de `IMF_names` y la de `IMFs` para ir cambiando los elementos y que la función se ejecute con cada uno de los elementos de las listas simultáneamente, pero me da este error:

```
NameError    Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 8
      5 IMF_names = ['imf1', 'imf2', 'imf3', 'imf4', 'imf5', 'imf6', 'imf7', 'imf8', 'imf9', 'imf10', 'imf11', 'imf12']
      7 for name in IMF_names:
----> 8     imf = eval(name)
      9     for IMF in IMFs:
     10         imf = my_get_next_imf(eval(IMF), zoom=(100,600))

File <string>:1

NameError: name 'imf1' is not defined
```

EL objetivo del código es que esta línea:

```
imf = my_get_next_imf(eval(IMF), zoom=(100,600))
```

quede así en cada iteración:

```
imf1 = my_get_next_imf(x, zoom=(100,600))
imf2 = my_get_next_imf(x - imf1, zoom=(100,600))
imf3 = my_get_next_imf(x - imf1 - imf2, zoom=(100,600))
```

La `x` ya es una variable en el código anterior e `imf1` se le asignará aplicando la función de `x` y así sucesivamente, esta es la idea. El
problema para hacerlo normalmente es que dentro de la función tengo un `x.copy()` y me da este error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'.
```

Por eso he usado `eval()`, antes he probado otras manera de pasar de string a otros formatos pero no me ha aceptado ninguno.

Por lo que creo debería poder asignar el nombre de las variables dentro
del bucle, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

¿Alguna ayudita porfa?
Gracias por ayudarme.

Xavier.

Comment: `eval` evalúa el código en un string. Entonces, si no hay ninguna variable llamada `imf1` da error.

Comment: La causa del error es simple. Cuando llega al eval, ejecuta código python, y, al intentar buscar la variable imf1 en tu script, no la está encontrando. La solución, sin embargo, depende del objetivo del código, el cual desconozco. Podrías explicarlo con más detalle editando la pregunta por favor? Así, será más facil ayudarte. Finalmente, creo que esto es [un problema xy](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY)

Comment: Hola Xavier, ¿my_get_next_imf que recibe como primer argumento?¿Un numero? ¿O una expresión matemática (usas alguna biblioteca de matemáticas simbolicas)? ¿O otro tipo de objeto? Lo digo porque me desconcierta lo de x.copy ya que si el primer argumento es un numero no entiendo la necesitad de copy dado que son objetos inmutables.

Comment: Ah claro perdona, recibe un vector de longitud = 144440000 de decimales muy largos y próximmos a cero, tipo: 1.9227e-8.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` evalúa una cadena de texto como código Python, el problema es que cuando haces `imf = eval(name)` la variable con el nombre "name" no existe, no está definida.

Dado que el valor de las variables `imf*` se establece en función del  retorno de la llamada a `my_get_next_imf` previa, debes crear la variable y asignarle su valor después de llamar a la función, no antes.

Puedes conseguirlo usando un solo ciclo for e iterando sobre IMFs e IMF_names a la par, con `zip`, y sustituyendo `eval` por `exec` (`eval` solo admite una sola expresion):

```
x = 13

def my_get_next_imf(x, zoom):
    return (x + 2) / x

IMFs = ['x', 'x - imf1', 'x - imf1 - imf2', 'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3', 'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4', 'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5', 'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5 - imf6',
    'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5 - imf6 - imf7', 'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5 - imf6 - imf7 - imf8', 'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5 - imf6 - imf7 - imf8 - imf9',
    'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5 - imf6 - imf7 - imf8 - imf9 - imf10', 'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5 - imf6 - imf7 - imf8 - imf9 - imf10 - imf11', 
    'x - imf1 - imf2 - imf3 - imf4 - imf5 - imf6 - imf7 - imf8 - imf9 - imf10 - imf11 - imf12']
IMF_names = ['imf1', 'imf2', 'imf3', 'imf4', 'imf5', 'imf6', 'imf7', 'imf8', 'imf9', 'imf10', 'imf11', 'imf12']


for name, IMF in zip(IMF_names, IMFs):
    exec(f"{name} = my_get_next_imf({IMF}, zoom=(100,600))")
```

La funcion `my_get_next_imf` y el valor de `x` son arbitrarios, son solo para hacer el ejemplo reproducible.

Hay muchas más formas de abordar el problema sin el uso de `eval`/`exec` o la creación de variables en tiempo de ejecución que se suelen considerar más "pitónicas" (explicitas y mas legibles). Por ejemplo, en tu caso podrías usar un diccionario o lista para almacenar las `imfs`:

```
x = 13

def my_get_next_imf(x, zoom):
    return (x + 2) / x

imfs = {}
prev = x
for i in range(1, 13):
    imf = my_get_next_imf(prev, zoom=(100, 600))
    prev -= imf
    imfs[f"imf{i}"] = imf
```

Lo que para el ejemplo daría un diccionario como el siguiente:

```
>>> imfs
 
{'imf1': 1.1538461538461537,
 'imf2': 1.1688311688311688,
 'imf3': 1.187312874251497,
 'imf4': 1.2107479382532096,
 'imf5': 1.2415674286736638,
 'imf6': 1.2841839778846276,
 'imf7': 1.3476138636593282,
 'imf8': 1.453937117464604,
 'imf9': 1.677516075505405,
 'imf10': 2.5693125308204983,
 'imf11': -0.5445576351417487,
 'imf12': -1.665559592068534}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probarlo, la función tiene cálculos complicados de spilines cúbicos a ver si me funciona.

Comment: El contenido de la función debería ser irrelevante siempre que la operacion `x - imf1`, `x - imf1 - imf2` ... sea válida. Dado que dices que es un vector/array de flotantes, siempre que el tipo de `x` e `imf*`  permita operaciones vectorizadas como los arrays de NumPy no debería haber problemas.

Comment: Del segundo código, no entiendo de donde se está pasando los elementos de la lista IMFs a la posición prev...? El primero se asigna a la variable prev  antes del bucle, pero los siguientes, x - imf1....?

Comment: El segundo código no usa la lista IMFs, dado que lo que tu código hace es simplemente pasarle a la función el resultado anterior menos la última IMF calculada (empezando por x), lo que se hace es simplemente en cada iteracion restarle a `prev` la ultima IMF calculada, de forma que en la primera iteración `prev` es `x`, en la segunda es `x - imf1` (es decir `prev = prev - my_get_next_imf(prev, zoom=(100, 600))`) y asi sucesivamente, `prev` actúa como "acumulador" teniendo como valor `x - imf1 - imf2 - ... -  imf{i}` al final de cada iteracion `i` del ciclo.

Comment: Entendido, muchísimas gracias por la explicación.

Comment: Efectivamente funcionan ambos, te estoy muy agradecido FJSevilla, sobre todo por el parendizaje !